# Is it correct and natural to ask "the card of what bank do you use" when you want to know the name of one's bank?

Tags: questions

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to ask *the card of what bank do you use* when you want to know the name of one's bank? If it doesn't, would it be more natural to ask *what bank is your card with*?

Comment: If you want to know where someone banks, all you need to do is ask them, "Where do you bank?"

Comment: The term is bank card. "Which or what bank card do you use?"

Comment: What bank card do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not natural.

It's difficult to think of any situation where you would want to phrase any question like this: *the X of which/what Y do you use?*  That kind of inversion is probably grammatical, but it's quite unusual.

Much more typical would be: *Which Y's X do you use*.  As in, *which bank's card do you use?*

But that's not the way we would ask this particular question.

If you want to know which bank a person uses, you'd just ask about the bank, not the card, e.g. *Which bank do you use?* or *Where do you bank?*

If you want to know about the bank associated with the card, you could ask, *Which bank issued your card?*